# DROP TABLE syntax commented in install scripts?

Tags: install

What is the purpose behind having `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` in commented SQL in Magento installers?

From **app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/mysql4-install-0.7.0.php**:

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('admin_assert')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('admin_assert')} (
```

I know in mysqldump certain comments can be executed - how is this used in Magento setup scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure it was inserted for debugging purposes to test the creation of the table.

Then it was commented to not use it anymore and forgotten :)

Look on the version, it is pre-beta.

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but it's used on the 1.4+ installer for Mage_Catalog, too: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/mysql4-install-1.4.0.0.0.php

Comment: Yep, not intended for evaluation. Consider this similar to all of the commented out code in Magento... [(ex)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php#L283)